# Region not displaying in module

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I'm working on a site where much of the back-end is handled by a site-specific custom module.

I have a sidebar region and within

Within module-thing.php is a call to `<?php print render($page['sidebar']); ?>` to print a region but it is not showing anything despite the region being set with content within the Blocks administration. I'm wondering if this is expected to work from within a module.. is there something i can do to show it?

I found this (right at the top) but doesn't seem to work in drupal 7 http://www.chrischen.me/content/drupal-how-access-regions-blocks-themes-or-modules..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to print page regions must be in your theme's page.tpl.php file, not in a file in a custom module.

If you want to put your code in a separate file (sidebar.php) you need to make sure it's included in page.tpl.php, like

```
include './sidebar.php'; // file is in the same folder as page.tpl.php
```

or

```
module_load_include('php', 'MYMODULE', 'sidebar'); // file is in a module folder
```

hope it helps

Comment: thanks! what *can* load a region? any tpl file in a theme? what about tpl files in modules?

Comment: I found this (right at the top) but doesn't seem to work in drupal 7 http://www.chrischen.me/content/drupal-how-access-regions-blocks-themes-or-modules..

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way was to do this:

```
<?php
  $region = block_get_blocks_by_region('region_name_here');
  print render($region);
?>
```

See the docs for more information:  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_get_blocks_by_region/7

In your module where you tried to print the sidebar region using the method used in a page template, use this snippet above instead. This method can also be used in html.tpl.php where the "usual" method cannot.

Comment: Hello. Code-only answers aren't usually that great. Person who asked, and future readers, are left on their own to figure out why, and that's bad. Especially if there is no obvious way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer to explain the solution a bit more. It's a handy Drupal function that I don't think is very well known.